# Series equality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is

$P=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{q(k)} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{i,j}= Q$

When $q$ is a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N^2$, and $a_{i,j} \ge 0$ for all $i,j \in \mathbb N$ ?

I think so, but I'm not sure whether my argument is right.

1, Similarly to re-arrangement of an absolutely convergent series, we could show that it doesn't matter how we re-arrange the series on left hand side, thus it doesn't matter what bijection q we consider, the sum will be the same.

2, Now, let's consider the onion-layer-like q bijection, where 
$q(1) = (1,1), 
q(2) = (2,1), 
q(3) = (2,2), 
q(4) = (1,2), 
q(5) = (1,3), 
q(6) = (2,3)$,
etc.

$Q \ge P$:
For any $m$, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{i,j} \ge \sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{m} a_{i,j} \ge \sum_{k=1}^{m} a_{q(k)}  $

$P \ge Q$:
$*$ Presuming $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{i,j} \in \mathbb R$ for all $i \in \mathbb N$ -
For any $\epsilon > 0$ we'll find an $s \in \mathbb N$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{s} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{i,j} > Q - \epsilon$. Now for each $t : s \ge t \ge 1$ , we will find $n_t$, such that  $\sum_{j=1}^{n_t} a_{t,j} \ge \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{t,j}  - {\epsilon \over {2^t} }$, and we will take a maximum of these $n_t$ defined as $n_0$. Now, $\sum_{i=1}^{s} \sum_{j=1}^{n_0} a_{i,j} \ge  \sum_{i=1}^{s} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{i,j} - \epsilon \ge   \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{i,j} - 2\epsilon$
Thus, $\sum_{k=1}^{(n_0 + s)^2} a_{q(k)} \ge Q - 2\epsilon$

$**$ If at least one sum $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{r,j} = \infty$ for some $r$, then $Q=\infty$, and since $\sum_{i=1}^{(m+1)^2} a_{q(i)}  \ge \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{r,j} $, thus $P = \infty$